# How to update large number of records via XML files?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm the developer for a real estate syndication website and am currently having trouble figuring out a way to update massive numbers of listings/records efficiently (2,000,000+ listings).

We currently accept XML feeds, containing real estate listings, from about ~20 different websites. Most of the incoming feeds are small (~100 or so listings), but we have a couple of XML feeds that contain ~1,000,000 listings. The small feeds are parsed fast and easy, however, the large feeds are taking upwards of 2-3 hours each.

The current "live" database table that contains the listings for viewing on the site is MyISAM. I chose MyISAM because ~95% of the queries to the table are `SELECT`s. Really the only time there are writes (UPDATE/INSERT queries) are during the time the XML feeds are being processed.

The current process is as follows:

1. There is a CRON in place that starts the main parsing script.
2. It loops through a `feeds` table and grabs the external XML feed source files. It then runs through said file and for each record in the XML file it checks against the `listings` table to see if a listing needs to be updated or inserted (if it's a new listing).

This is all happening against the live table. What I'd like to find out is if anybody has any better logic to make these updates/inserts happen in the background so as to not slow down the production tables, and ultimately, the user experience.

Would a *delta* table be the best choice? Maybe do all the heavy work on a separate database and just copy the new table over to the production database? On a separate *workhorse* domain altogether? Should I have a separate `listings` table that does all the parsing which would be InnoDB instead of MyISAM?

What we're trying to accomplish is to have our system be able to update listings frequently throughout the day without slowing the site down. Our competitors boast that they are updating their listings every 5 minutes in some cases. I just don't see how that's even possible.

I'm working right now so this is more of a brain dump just to get the ball rolling. If anybody would like me to provide table schematics, I'd be more than happy.

In summary: I'm looking for a way to frequently update millions of records in our database (daily) via a couple dozen external XML feeds/files. I just need some logic on how to effectively, and efficiently, make this happen so as to not drag the production server down with it.

Comment: `So this question is more of a discussion.` which is off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: Would have been helpful of you to point me in the right direction instead of just calling out a newbie on his mistakes. Cheers.

Comment: Don't worry about it @Marcus - a suit of armour is sometimes useful here! but even for off-topic questions, useful titbits can sometimes be gleaned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, for your existing 3 hour import, try wrapping every 100 inserts in a transaction. They will be written to the database in one go, and that might speed things up dramatically. Play around with the 100 value - the best value will depend on how resilient you want it, and how much memory your transaction cache has. (This will of course require you to switch to a different engine).

For providers that are known to offer larger files, try keeping a copy of the previous XML download, and then do a text diff between the old one and the new one. If you set your context settings (i.e. the number of unchanged lines around changed lines) sufficiently you might be able to capture the primary keys of changed items. You would then just do a small number of updates.

Of course, it would help if your providers maintain the order of their XML listing. If they don't, a text sort then a diff may still be faster than importing everything.

FWIW, I think a complete refresh every 5 minutes is probably not feasible. I expect your providers would not be happy with you downloading 1M records at this frequency!

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I like the idea of offloading the work to a XML comparison script instead of running against the db to do my checks. I'm going to chew on this one for a bit. Would you say that Innodb is the best choice then? I saw you mentioned transactions which led me to believe you're suggesting I switch my table engines from MyISAM to Innodb. I don't have any experience with Innodb. I just know it requires much more config tweaking then MyISAM. Any tips/links you could share with setting up Innodb?

Comment: Further.. I guess a large problem has always been the table-locking of MyISAM. Innodb has row-locking which would make for a far more efficient, high writes script, correct? Server specs FYI: 16GB RAM, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 V2 @ 3.30GHz (8 processors), MySQL v5.1 (we're in the midst of upgrading to v5.6, but that could take some time. So we'll be on v5.1 for the next little while).

Comment: I don't know much about MySQL tuning, but the best approach generally is to build a copy of your live environment, try various changes and then get metrics for each configuration. Yes, to get transactions you'll need InnoDB. I'd start with bunching writes together as that is the easiest win, and then go from there.